# Am having troubles with django-parler 2.0.1 after i had applied migration to translations, it won't show Products fields in admin site

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-parler

[image]this is my setting for translations in the models.py file, django-parler 2.0.1 won't show fields for Products in the admin site after I had synch migrations. I am currently using Django 3.0.3.

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields





class Category(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
            name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                    db_index=True),
            slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                                    db_index=True,
                                    unique=True)
        )

    class Meta:
        # ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category',
                           args=[self.slug])


class Product(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
            name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True),
            slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True),
            description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                              blank=True)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    #class Meta:
    #    ordering = ('name',)
    #    index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('shop:product_detail',
                           args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

I have registered the model in the admin.py file but it won't show the fields for product description and price all I get is the translated tab.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product
from parler.admin import TranslatableAdmin


@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']

    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
            return {'slug': ('name',)}


@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug', 'price',
                    'available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_editable = ['price', 'available']

    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
            return {'slug': ('name',)}
```

I wonder what am doing wrong that I am getting this and I wonder if there's a better way to make translate configurations with Django-parler 2.0.1. any suggestions is welcomed!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was able to fix the problem by first deleting all migrations and I also had to trash my database and switch to PostgreSQL and after that, I reapplied migrations and it worked. All fields are now visible in the admin site now yippee! but be mindful to make a backup of your database because everything will be deleted.. [image]